# Challenges in measuring the output voltage of an H-bridge using an instrumentation amp and resistive divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, h-bridge, instrumentation-amplifier

Design a circuit that allows me to measure the output voltage of a full H-bridge. Essentially, I'm using a resistive divider for this purpose. The simplified design is as follows:

[image]

I had issues with the output signal of IOP1. So, I isolated the resistive dividers from the entire circuit and measured the output signals using an oscilloscope. To my surprise, this is the graph I observed coming out of my circuit:

Measurement between A(Positive probe of the oscilloscope) and B(oscilloscope ground):
[image]

Measurement between T1(Positive probe of the oscilloscope) and B(oscilloscope ground):
[image]

Measurement between T1(Positive probe of the oscilloscope) and T2(oscilloscope ground):
[image]

I've conducted simulations, and this shouldn't be happening. I should be getting a PWM signal at the same frequency as "PWM_SGN," but attenuated to a peak value of approximately 1.14V. What could be causing this issue? Here's an image of the PCB:

[image]

[image]
In the last image, I've added a red line that traces the entire path of the two signals before reaching the instrumentation amp. I think they are too close, and the parasitic capacitance is excessive for such a small signal. Perhaps I should have separated them a bit more.

---

By the way:

- I forgot to mention: the PWM signals work like this: in one branch, the lower N-MOSFET is turned on while the upper one is off, and in the other branch, both N-MOSFETs switch between on and off alternately at a frequency of 2.5kHz.
- In the tests I conducted using the oscilloscope, I replaced all the resistors with 220k ones. That's why the peak-to-peak voltage on the oscilloscope is 11.4V. However, I'm getting the same result when I use the values from the first circuit I provided.

Comment: How exactly did you "measure between" nodes? What type of probe, oscilloscope, and circuit and/or scope grounding is connected, if any? What is the amp: circuit, type, power supply etc.?

Comment: Did you connect the oscilloscope ground lead to something other than the ground of the circuit?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I've edited the question already, and there's no need to add more information (like the amplifier or the power source and everything else) because the issue originates from the resistors. Basically, I created a circuit with just the 4 resistors you see in the first diagram and measured the outputs I mentioned above, obtaining those strange curves

Comment: Well we still need to know grounding because by default, probe ground goes to scope ground goes to earth ground, and if your circuit is also earthed, that's going to make a big error, and it's a common newbie oversight. Even if the circuit and/or scope isn't grounded, a similar effect occurs at AC (capacitance (and other impedance) between grounds) again disturbing the waveform. Now you put me in the situation of probably answering the question in the comments, because I can't know if this is actually the answer, and I must reveal the answer to determine if it was correct.